# Delegate combining in C#

Tags: c#

Say I have a delegate field in a class in C#:

```
public Action TrainsAreComing;
```

to which I then do, in some instance method:

```
TrainsAreComing = FirstSubscriber;
```

and then:

```
TrainsAreComing += SecondSubscriber
```

I've read some SO answers where people say this statement translates to:

```
 TrainsAreComing += (Action)Delegate.Combine(TrainsAreComing, new Action(SecondSubscriber));
```

Which I found not to be true, because here you're actually combining FirstSubscriber + FirstSubscriber + SecondSubscriber which is not what `TrainsAreComing += SecondMethod` does (just combining FirstSubscriber with SecondSubscriber).

So what's really going on in the background and how would you write the de-sugared version of `TrainsAreComing += SecondMethod` using `Delegate.Combine`?

Comment: i think the `+=` operator was typo. it should be `TrainsAreComing = (Action)Delegate.Combine...`

Comment: I agree on @M.kazemAkhgary. See this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173175.aspx).

Comment: An Action isn't an event. `+=` is used to subscribe to events. Perhaps you wanted to type `=`?

Comment: No it's not a typo. Fields in C# get default values and this works if the delegate instance is a field.

Comment: @daremkd Then if it is not a typo, it is wrong. It is like saying `i += i + j` (with `i` and `j` integers) and then complaining of the result. Consider `Delegate.Combine` to be the `+` operator.

Comment: You wrote that you found that piece of code in another SO answer. Which? I'm also of the opinion that M.kazem Akhgary is right.

Comment: Okay let's say it's "wrong" (I changed my original question), but still my answer wasn't about the first subscriber, but about the second. My point about the null was that this is possible: Action del = null;
del += MyMethod; now not sure how right or wrong it is, but it works. Anyway, you could also do del = MyMethod too..

Comment: I think you didn't understand the problem. It was not the assignment of FirstSubscriber. This `TrainsAreComing += (Action)Delegate.Combine(TrainsAreComing, new Action(SecondSubscriber));` is wrong. You should replace `+=` with `=`.

Comment: Oh wow, I overlook that. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Asking roslyn is always a good idea: http://goo.gl/JL8gjy

```
public static void Main()
{
    Action ac = Method1;
    ac += Method2;
}
```

is

```
public static void Main()
{
    Action a = new Action(C.Method1);
    a = (Action)Delegate.Combine(a, new Action(C.Method2));
}
```

I'll note that the `+=` operator is normally translated to a `+` and a separate `=` operator, like:

```
ac = ac + Method2;
```

that is much easier to see that is very similar to the `Delegate.Combine(ac, Method2)` .